# Python can't execute terminal script, using sh nor bash

Tags: python, linux, bash, sh, fedora

i hope you guys can help me with this problem because i'm really stuck... I'm trying to execute a program from python and, for some reason, it doesn't work. The script is located at:

```
path/to/teqc
```

I've added this line to the .bashrc file:

```
alias teqc='path/to/teqc'
```

and, when i run

`teqc -tr d input >output`

on a terminal it works fine... but, if i run it on a python program, it shows:

```
sh: teqc: command not found
```

the code i've been using on python is:

```
os.system('teqc -tr d input >output')
```

I tried using

```
subprocess.Popen('teqc -tr d input >output', shell=True, executable="/bin/bash")
```

but the only result was to change the error message to

```
/bin/bash: teqc: command not found
```

Any help would be really appreciated :)

P.D. I forgot to specify, the operating system is Fedora 21

Comment: `/path/to/teqc` might not be the same as `path/to/teqc`.  Is this a typo in your question?

Comment: You could just add `/path/to` to your `PATH` variable, which may (or may not) be more elegant.

Comment: @Isaac Yes, sorry about that. It's just a typo.

Comment: @VHarisop I read that question before posting but it didn't help me

Comment: @ShellFish The program has to be able to run on any computer, so I prefer not to modify more files than necessary on my machine

Comment: @NicolásGodoy Adding something to `PATH` doesn't require you to edit anything more than `.bashrc` which you're already editing. You just delete the alias and add `export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/scripts"`. Also make sure when the script gets called, the correct user is process owner, otherwise the `.bashrc` read will be a different one.

Comment: `os.system()` most likely cares nothing about any aliases you've set... Try putting the full path in instead of just the program name. Alternatively, make sure that your `PATH` contains `path/to` so that the program can be found when the shell searches for it...

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest creating a symbolic link to your program .

```
ln -s /path/to/teqc /usr/bin/teqc
```

Comment: It works!! Thank you very much. Now I just must modify the code to create a symbolic link on every computer that run the script. I'm really thankful :)

Comment: Nice, +1 for elegant solution!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the environment variable PATH is not the same when you run the command in the code using subprocess.

1. One solution would be to have a soft link in as suggested in the previous answer
2. Other thing you can do is to have your code set the environment before you execute your command using subprocess the os module comes has a os.environ dictionary which can be used to append the path using something like this

   ```
   import os
   import subprocess
   os.environ['PATH'] += ":/path/to/teqc"
   subprocess.Popen(['teqc -tr d input'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
   ```